# In groovy - how to add single quotes in list of versions and remove the white spaces?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

In groovy - how to add single quotes in list of versions and remove the white spaces?

```
def list = [1.0,
1.9,
1.11.0,
1.6,
1.7,
1.7.1,
1.8]

List modifiedList = list.collect{ '"' + it + '"'}
but this adds double quotes and if i  change the 


List modifiedList = list.collect{ ''' + it + '''}
and its not understanding the single quotes.
```

**expected output**

```
['1.0',
'1.9', 
'1.11.0',
'1.6',
'1.7',
'1.7.1',
'1.8']
```

I want to add single quotes and remove the white spaces from front and back of versions. Tried trim() but it's not removing properly.

Comment: if you want a single quote as a String, just surround it with double quotes: `"'"` 
Result: `'`

Comment: "I want to add single quotes and remove the white spaces from front and back of versions. Tried trim() but it's not removing properly." - There is no white space in any of the version values you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
def list = [1.0,
1.9,
1.11.0,
1.6,
1.7,
1.7.1,
1.8]
```

That is not valid Groovy code and won't compile.  In particular, `1.11.0` and `1.7.1` are invalid expressions.  You would have to define those like this:

```
def list = ['1.0',
'1.9',
'1.11.0',
'1.6',
'1.7',
'1.7.1',
'1.8']
```